# Lambda callback depends on its parameters

Tags: c++, lambda, template-meta-programming

I am writing a library where the user provides a callback as a lambda. In the default scenario I want to just call the lambda and pass the back an object.

Now there are non trivial senarios where the user may want the context as well. So I want to be able to use the same callback mechanism and just allow the user to add a context as a parameter to their lambda and I will then pass both the object and the context.

I can't quite get SFINAE to work.

I have simplified the code to this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Context {};


template<typename F>
struct UseContext
{
    // I want to set this value to 0 or 1 based on the parameters
    // in F but can't quite get this to work.
    enum {value = 0 };
};


template<typename F, typename T, bool useContext = UseContext<F>::value>
struct Caller;

template<typename F, typename T>
struct Caller<F, T, true>
{
    void operator()(F& func, Context& context, T& object)
    {
        func(context, object);
    }
};
template<typename F, typename T>
struct Caller<F, T, false>
{
    void operator()(F& func, Context&, T& object)
    {
        func(object);
    }
};



template<typename T, typename F>
void doWork(F&& func)
{
  Context  context;
  T        object;

  /// STUFF
  Caller<F,T>  caller;
  caller(func, context, object);
}
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    // if UseContext::value == 0 then this compiles.
    // This is the normal situation.
    doWork<std::string>([](std::string const& x){ std::cout << x << "\n";});

    // if UseContext::value == 1 then this compiles.
    // This is if the user wants more context about the work.
    // most of the time this extra parameter is not required.
    // So I don't want to force the user to add it to the parameter
    // list of the lambda.
    doWork<std::string>([](Context&, std::string const& x){ std::cout << x << "\n";});
}
```

Or if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: if the user wants context, can he just capture it as reference in the capture list? for me, as one who might use this library, it's semms more intuitive. wants some context? capture it as reference.

Comment: @DavidHaim: You can't because the context is not available at the point where `doWork()` is being called. It is coming from inside the library. Capture list capture context at the point where the lambda is created (not where it is used).

Comment: I understand your problem now,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expression SFINAE:

```
template<class F, class T>
auto call(F& func, Context& context, T& object) -> decltype(func(context, object), void())
{
   func(context, object);
}
template<class F, class T>
auto call(F& func, Context&, T& object) -> decltype(func(object), void())
{
    func(object);
}
```

Then just `call(func, context, object)`. This is ambiguous if both forms are valid. If you want to disambiguate, just add a dummy parameter and do the usual `int`/`long` trick.

Comment: That seems way to easy :-)

Comment: @loki note that in msvc 2013 2025, that may not work, as it falls under 'expression SFINAE'.  I think there is a tag dispatching variant, however.

Comment: For those that don't like the comma operator, you can use `std::result_of`: http://pastebin.com/gGcyHr3X

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to use `std::is_constructible` plus `std::enable_if`:

```
template<typename F,typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<std::function<void(T const&)>,F>::value>:type doWork(F func)
{
//...
}

template<typename F,typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<std::function<void(Context&,T const&)>,F>::value>:type doWork(F func)
{
//...
}
```

explenation - each `std::function` can be built from the equivilant lambda. here we are testing using `std::enable_if` if you can build a `std::function<void(T)>` or a `std::function<void(Context,T)>` and re-wire the correct function in compile time.